# gdb suddenly starts ignoring breakpoints

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

This just happened randomly while debugging. I've restarted the terminal (i'm using ubuntu on windows specifically) and even my pc, yet the problem still persists.[image]

I set a breakpoint at line 43, but when i run the code, it jumps right to line 55 for no apparent reason.

edit: I actually figured out that gdb is working as it should. I just overlooked that i set a breakpoint in a for loop body that my code couldn't reach.

Comment: Did you disable optimization when compiling?

Comment: How are you compiling the program?